# Running a python script as task from task scheduler

Tags: python, batch-file, spyder

I have a python script which I am able to run it locally from my machine and works fine. I am using spyder for coding. This python script needs to run daily at a certain time so I created a basic task under task scheduler. 
The way I am doing this is in the action script I am putting my pythonw.exe and I am adding my python script as a action argument.

The thing is task scheduler triggers the task and script is not producing any outputs. I am reading a files from the shared drive in  my native file.

I also tried to create the batch file and run the batch file but same issue.
[image]

Not sure what is wrong.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have the full path to `pythonw.exe` and your script in each field? Is there an error code, or just no output?

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik I did tried import sys and print(sys.executable) to get the path, I got C:\Users\sp22\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe as a path. and that is the path I am using in the action path. The problem here is no output and no error.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik Under task scheduler I am getting a code 2147942402

Comment: I believe that code is for file not found. Is the full path to your script in the action field?

Comment: @VorsprundurchTechnik here is the screenshot how I am doing this attached the scrren shot in the original question not sure if I am doing it in correct way

Comment: Export the task to XML, [edit] your post to include the contents.  What does your Python script do?  You may need to post that as well.  Your error code is `0x80070002‬ File Not Found`.

Comment: It looks like task scheduler not able to find the python. exe or my python is not activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the batch file and put that under the task sechduler and it worked fine. It looks like I had an issues with the access permissions as I have two accounts on my laptop.
Thanks Everyone for the help.